# Why print not wait result of async function?

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter project:

```
Future<Position> getCurrentPosition({
    LocationAccuracy desiredAccuracy = LocationAccuracy.best,
    GeolocationPermission locationPermissionLevel =
        GeolocationPermission.location,
  }) async {
```

in my class:

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';

class TestAsync {
  var _logger = Logger();

  Future<void> main() async {
    _logger.d("TestAsync: main: Fetching user order...");
    _logger.d(await createOrderMessage());
  }

  Future<String> createOrderMessage() async {
    _logger.d("TestAsync: createOrderMessage: BEFORE_WAIT ");
    var order = await fetchUserOrder();
    return 'TestAsync: createOrderMessage: AFTER_WAIT Your order is: $order';
  }

  Future<Position> fetchUserOrder() async {
    _logger.d("TestAsync: fetchUserOrder: ");
    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
      Geolocator()
          .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
          .then((value) {
            _logger.d("TestAsync: fetchUserOrder: index = $index then_value = $value");
      });
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I use **async** function `fetchUserOrder`. And to call this function I use

```
 await fetchUserOrder();
```

So the result must be:

1. Execute `fetchUserOrder`
2. After finish `fetchUserOrder` only then print:

   **TestAsync: createOrderMessage: AFTER_WAIT Your order is...**

But the result is another

```
I/flutter (11975): │  createState:
I/flutter (11975): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): │ #0   _SignInScreenState.initState (package:flutter_sample/screens/signin_screen.dart:29:13)
I/flutter (11975): │ #1   StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4649:58)
I/flutter (11975): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter (11975): │  initState:
I/flutter (11975): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): │ #0   TestAsync.main (package:flutter_sample/service/TestAsync.dart:26:13)
I/flutter (11975): │ #1   _SignInScreenState.initState (package:flutter_sample/screens/signin_screen.dart:36:21)
I/flutter (11975): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter (11975): │  TestAsync: main: Fetching user order...
I/flutter (11975): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): │ #0   TestAsync.createOrderMessage (package:flutter_sample/service/TestAsync.dart:31:13)
I/flutter (11975): │ #1   TestAsync.main (package:flutter_sample/service/TestAsync.dart:27:21)
I/flutter (11975): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter (11975): │  TestAsync: createOrderMessage: BEFORE_WAIT 
I/flutter (11975): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): │ #0   TestAsync.fetchUserOrder (package:flutter_sample/service/TestAsync.dart:39:13)
I/flutter (11975): │ #1   TestAsync.createOrderMessage (package:flutter_sample/service/TestAsync.dart:33:23)
I/flutter (11975): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter (11975): │  TestAsync: fetchUserOrder: 
I/flutter (11975): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): │ #0   _SignInScreenState.build (package:flutter_sample/screens/signin_screen.dart:41:13)
I/flutter (11975): │ #1   StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4628:28)
I/flutter (11975): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter (11975): │  build:
I/flutter (11975): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): │ #0   TestAsync.main (package:flutter_sample/service/TestAsync.dart:27:13)
I/flutter (11975): │ <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (11975): │ #1   _SignInScreenState.initState (package:flutter_sample/screens/signin_screen.dart:36:21)
I/flutter (11975): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter (11975): │  TestAsync: createOrderMessage: AFTER_WAIT Your order is: null
I/flutter (11975): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): │ #0   TestAsync.fetchUserOrder.() (package:flutter_sample/service/TestAsync.dart:44:21)
I/flutter (11975): │ #1   _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
I/flutter (11975): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter (11975): │  TestAsync: fetchUserOrder: index = 1 then_value = Lat: 37.4219983, Long: -122.084
I/flutter (11975): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): │ #0   TestAsync.fetchUserOrder.() (package:flutter_sample/service/TestAsync.dart:44:21)
I/flutter (11975): │ #1   _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
I/flutter (11975): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter (11975): │  TestAsync: fetchUserOrder: index = 0 then_value = Lat: 37.4219983, Long: -122.084
I/flutter (11975): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (11975): │ #0   TestAsync.fetchUserOrder.() (package:flutter_sample/service/TestAsync.dart:44:21)
I/flutter (11975): │ #1   _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
I/flutter (11975): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter (11975): │  TestAsync: fetchUserOrder: index = 3 then_value = Lat: 37.4219983, Long: -122.084
```

:

As you can see the **AFTER_WAIT Your order is** print **BEFORE**

```
TestAsync: fetchUserOrder: index =
```

Why?

Comment: You're not returning a `Future`(or anything for that matter) from `fetchUserOrder`. You should have gotten a message from static analysis that your should pay attention to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add `await` inside the Future in front any operation you wan it to complete first before jumping to next line

Answer (score 1):

I found solution:

```
 Future<String> createOrderMessage() async {
    _logger.d("TestAsync: createOrderMessage: BEFORE_WAIT ");
    // The "await" keyword only works within an async function.
    var order = await fetchUserOrder();
    // The next line will execute only after finish fetchUserOrder() because use "await and async".
    return 'TestAsync: createOrderMessage: AFTER_WAIT Your order is: $order';
  }

  Future<Position> fetchUserOrder() async {
    _logger.d("TestAsync: fetchUserOrder: START");
    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
      await Geolocator()
          .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
          .then((value) {
        _logger
            .d("TestAsync: fetchUserOrder: index = $index then_value = $value");
      });
    }
  }
```

This help:

```
await Geolocator()
```

Comment: good you found it, thats what i told you  add await inside the Future